# Running JUnit test from command line: initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)

Tags: java, linux, junit, junit4, noclassdeffounderror

All files are in the same folder. I had no trouble compiling using

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/junit4.jar <classname>.java <classname>.java <classname>.java NumberDisplayTest.java
```

But when I run the test

```
java -cp .:/usr/share/java/junit4.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore NumberDisplayTest
```

I get this [image]

What am I missing?

But if I do any sort of typo like writing ...org.junit.runner.JUnitCore NumberDisplayTest**s**

I get something else:
[image]

I have more tests to run, however, this was just one class I wanted to test. 
How do I do if I have multiple classes that are dependent and want to test them all the once, or do I have to compile and test them individually?
I can't do anything with the classpath as I suspect it may be involved because it's a uni computer.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried including the clock package name: `java -cp .:/usr/share/java/junit4.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore clock.NumberDisplayTest` ?

Comment: Yes, I get  
    initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult), same as the last picture. @explv